# Unable to boot from secondary SSD despite being detected by os-prober

Tags: boot, partition, dual-boot, grub, uefi

I have a PC that does **not** support UEFI. It only supports Legacy BIOS.

I have an SSD with only 2 partitions of Fedora and Debian installed on it. There is no UEFI or MBR partition. This SSD was used originally with a UEFI PC that had two drives. The first drive contained an EFI partition which contained a reference to this second disk that contained the Fedora/Debian. This second disk was originally GPT.

The computer that those two drives were in has now broken, and so I want to use this SSD with Fedora/Debian on my legacy BIOS PC. I used gdisk to convert the disk from GPT to MBR. I used several grub utilities (including os-prober) and it successfully detected this second drive and added the entries of Fedora/Debian to my Grub.

The problem is when I try to boot. When I select the entry for Fedora or Debian, the screen turns black and Grub does nothing. When I use the "ls" command on Grub's command line, Grub hangs and I cannot escape and must restart my PC with the power button. The fans rev up on my PC, so I assume that GRUB is trying to detect something but it clearly fails. In the end, GRUB fails to detect this secondary drive. So the problem is that when I boot into Linux, the disk is detected, but it is not detected by Grub when booting. In addition, my BIOS detects the disk, but can't figure out how to boot from it since there is no MBR on it.

I think having no MBR on this second disk is what is causing the problem. However, I am not sure, since when I used this disk on my UEFI PC I didn't need to have an EFI partition on the drive. If I need to create the MBR partition, I do not want to lose data and am not aware of any tools that could create this MBR for me without losing data. If necessary, I can create space at the beginning of the drive to create the MBR partition if needed.

Ultimately I can't find much information about this strange scenario and I am not very knowledgeable about booting and SSDs. So please have patience with me.

I would greatly appreciate if someone can help.

Here is an example GRUB configuration for Debian:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,msdos2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  b9842339-1f35-4b00-8f05-ef3125917197
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9842339-1f35-4b00-8f05-ef3125917197
fi
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=b9842339-1f35-4b00-8f05-ef3125917197 ro quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-11-amd64
```

Comment: Also, this is my first time making a post on this site so I apologize in advance if I broke any rules. Please let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Comment: You do not have to convert from gpt to use BIOS boot. But gpt does require a bios_grub partition of 1 or 2MB unformatted. And then you need grub-pc for BIOS boot in place of grub-efi-amd64 used for UEFI boot.  If you converted, you changed every UUID, so at minimum have to totally reinstall grub as all references using UUIDs will be wrong. Also fstab entries. compare: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint` and `cat /etc/fstab`